# how to call c function which is of type static pyobject inside c

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-2.7, embedding

I want to call a function of static PyObject type which I described inside my c program in the inside of that that c program. How to call this function? What will be the (Pyobject self) argument? I understand that the "args" argument will be any module name.

I have tried calling `mynewfunction("",Pfunc)`. Here my `mynewfunction` is defined as `static PyObject mynewfunction(Pyobject *self, PyObject *args)`. 
But it did not work. How to call this function from inside of C after `PyInitialize()`? What I will put in place of *self?

```
#include <Python.h>
 static PyObject *string_arr_conversion(PyObject *self, PyObject args){
     Pyobject *str_arr;
     int i;
     .......
     .......
 }
 int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
     ............
     ............
     Py_Initialize();
     .............
     string_arr_conversion("",pFunc);
 }
```

here I kept the self argument empty. What we need to put in place of self argument? Or how to call this function in c ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be a function and not a method, since it does not belong to a class, you would use `NULL` for self. So calling the function with something like

```
 string_arr_conversion(NULL, pFunc);
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried to call by using the above format but still I not getting my desired result. I checked before passing that is pFunc is NULL or not i saw it is not NULL. But if you see my class defination it is going inside of this if block.```if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "o", &str_arr)) {
           retun NULL; }```.